# Determine colours used in psd file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, layers

How can I easily determine which colours were used in a specific psd file without having to dig through every layer using the colour picker tool?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, just upload the photo to [Color Explorer](http://www.colorexplorer.com/imageimport.aspx) and it will analyze it and tell you what colors are used.

It can't import PSD, but you can just save it as a PNG or whatever and upload it.

There's also [adobe kuler](https://kuler.adobe.com) (sorry forgot about it!), just click the camera icon (create from an image), import the image, it will show you the colors, hit save and it will show you the color code.

Comment: That'd require you to hover over every single pixel in every single layer in the document to get the colors. The OP even says *"without having to dig through every layer using the colour picker tool"*

Comment: @slhck true, i edited the answer

Comment: The online tool allows JPG and PNG up to 250 kB, so no PSDs unfortunately.

Comment: @slhck i think kuler is the best tool, it's made by adobe, if that's can't import psds, i think nothing can, because if adobe didn't do it, no one will, i might be wrong though

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am just sure i read an article recently about a website someone created that lets you upload psds but cant remember where. Maymbe smashing magazine, codrops or some third site. Annoying